# Facing not found with retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

hope you are doing good. 
I have a problem with my code. I want to use retrofit to reach a server. I have done it once, with the same project, and every were fine. actually retrofit cannot reach the server, yet Postman can. In order to be sure the server is receiving request, I have added logging. With Postman logs are shown, but there is no logs with retrofit. So, I have decided to create a new Android project with the same configuration for retrofit, and the logging in the onResponse method in retrofit Callback says `Not Found`. Maybe I'm too tired to see the problem. I need your help please. Here is my code :

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String AUTENTIFICATION_BASE_URL = "http://192.168.11.241:8080/";

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitAutentificationInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(AUTENTIFICATION_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

```
public interface ScanAPI {

    @GET("api/get-data")
    public Call<CodeDatas> getData(@Query("datas") String data);
}
```

And in the MainActivity class there is this method.

```
public void loadScanData() {
        String data ="data content";

        ScanAPI scanAPI = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitAutentificationInstance().create(ScanAPI.class);
        Call<CodeDatas> call = scanAPI.getData(data);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CodeDatas>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CodeDatas> call, Response<CodeDatas> response) {
                Log.d("SCAN-RESPONSE", response.message()); // Not Found message
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CodeDatas> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("SCAN-ERROR", t.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
```

EDIT

I have tried to use OkHttp, and it is working fine. the code :

```
private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String data ="data content";
            String str = "";
            try {
                str = run("http://192.168.11.241:8080/api/get-data?datas="+data);
                Log.d("SCAN-RESPONSE", str);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and post screenshots of Postman client? I don't see any problem with your code. Are you connected to the same network on both the mobile phone and computer (LAN)? Try to access the same URL from the mobile phone browser (Chome, Firefox, or Opera). If it doesn't work, try to disable Firewall in your PC (if you're using any anti-virus programs disable that also)

Comment: It's probably getting empty message. Have you tried response.body()

Comment: @Shashanth I'm on the same network. the url is working from the phone browser.

Comment: @Priyank-py reponse.body() return null